# Confusion in "I have..." versus "I have had..."

Tags: tenses

I am a bit confused in which one is better and why. I have two sentences below.

> I have over 10 years of experience in this field.

or

> I have had over 10 years of experience in this field.

Can anyone explain with logic, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence communicates the value that the speaker has and can bring right now. The second sentence communicates that value may exist, but it relegates the occurrence to a time before now that it is unspecific about. The first sentence better communicates experience as an available commodity for the reason that the speaker has it right now.

More to the point, the first sentence suggests that the speaker has current knowledge of the field (due to the [present tense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_tense) of the verb "have"; synonym: "possess"). The second sentence communicates that the speaker has knowledge of the field but having happened before now (due to the [present perfect tense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect) of the verb phrase, "have had", which is in the form: [present] [past]). Beyond that the experience happened before now, the second sentence does not specify when: it could have been yesterday, 30 years ago, or any other time before now.

Consider this change to the first sentence (replacing "have" with "possess"):

> I possess over 10 years of experience in this field.

Consider this change to the second sentence (replacing "have had" with "have possessed"):

> I have possessed over 10 years of experience in this field.

The altered first sentence retains its intended meaning. The altered second sentence does not. The second sentence in this form should point out the issue of how unspecific the statement is. To use the present perfect tense and keep the intended meaning, choose a word that specifically keeps ownership regardless of time:

> I have gained over 10 years of experience in this field.

Comment: I wish I could have the ability upvoted more than 1. In fact I cannot upvote even 1. Very well explained. Thank you!

Comment: That being said, the second variant would commonly be used as an intended paraphrase of the first, and would normally be understood to mean the same thing.